Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: edit.blade.php
hi everyone i need fix this issue please
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /home/user/public_html/core/resources/views/templates/basic/user/seller/service/edit.blade.php)
in /home/user/public_html/core/storage/framework/views/8f482c9949e1cc7f351acb9050a05cacc25d6799.php (line 113)
line 113
<?php $__currentLoopData = $service->tag; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $name): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>

The Image issue

$__currentLoopData is not an array or iteratable. Can you show your actual blade edit.blade.php file? This is the compiled version, so won't reflect what you're actually trying to do.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
